# How to catch manual dropdown change, made by the user itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

How can I catch a dropdown change made by the user itself and not when the page is loaded and the default value is assigned to that dropdown?

I tried with e.originalEvent, but it's not working.

```
$(self.options.selectChange).change(function (e){
   // check if the change event is a user-triggered event
   if (e.originalEvent) {
      ...
   }
});
```

I have a form which have a lot of dropdowns and each of them has a default value which is set on page load. That action is considered a dropdown, triggering the code above, but I want to trigger the above code only when a user manually change the option.

How can I do that?

Comment: hi, take a look at my answer, if this does not help you coud provide a working example and i'll take a look. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for `event.isTrigger`

```js
$('select').change(function(e) {
  console.log(e.isTrigger ? 'triggered' : 'manual')
})

$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('select').trigger('change')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select>

<button>Trigger</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be to *mark* your handlers. Create a custom function with a `label` parameter.

```js
const customHandler = (label) => {

  if (typeof label !== 'string') {
    label = 'defaultLabel';
  }

  return (jQueryEvent, customData) => {

    let customLabel = customData ? customData.name : label;
    let jqElem = $(jQueryEvent.currentTarget);

    // you can use IF statements here based on your customLabel value

    console.log('this element was triggered by', customLabel);

  }

}

$("select").on('change', customHandler('changedByUser'));

const customTrigger = (label) => () => {

  $("select").trigger('change', {
    name: label || 'pageload'
  })

}

window.onload = customTrigger();
setTimeout(customTrigger('this-timeout'), 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>

<br />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even it's about a couple of more lines of code, it is working as the above answer.